# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/tracing/SpanReceiverHost

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, hive

I am running Hadoop 2.8.1 and Hive 2.3.0
I am tring to read values from an a table created in Hive
and the current exception is

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.tracing.SpanReceiverHost
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

And here is the code that I have used to read the tables

```
 public static final String HIVEURL = "jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000";
    public static final String DB_NAME = "default";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "order_line";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HiveConf hiveConf = new HiveConf();
        //hiveConf.setVar(HiveConf.ConfVars.METASTOREURIS, HIVEURL);
        HiveMetaStoreClient hiveClient = new HiveMetaStoreClient(hiveConf);

        Job job =Job.getInstance();
        TaskAttemptContext ctx = new TaskAttemptContextImpl(job.getConfiguration(), new TaskAttemptID());
        HCatInputFormat hcif = HCatInputFormat.setInput(job, DB_NAME, TABLE_NAME);


        HCatSchema allCols = hcif.getTableSchema(job.getConfiguration());
        List<HCatFieldSchema> usedList = new ArrayList<>();
        usedList.add(allCols.get(2)); // por ex...
        HCatSchema someCols = new HCatSchema(usedList);
        hcif.setOutputSchema(job, someCols);

        for(InputSplit split: hcif.getSplits(job)) {
            RecordReader<WritableComparable, HCatRecord> rr = hcif.createRecordReader(split,ctx);
            rr.initialize(split, ctx);

            while(rr.nextKeyValue()) {
                HCatRecord record = rr.getCurrentValue();
                // usar record.get(...) para obter a coluna...
                //Object o = record.get(1);
                //System.out.println(o.toString());

            }

            rr.close();
        }

        hiveClient.close();
    }
```

And here it is the Pom file that I have used

org.apache.hive.hcatalog
            hive-hcatalog-core
            2.3.0
        
        
            org.apache.hive.hcatalog
            hive-hcatalog
            0.13.1-cdh5.3.5
        
        
        
            org.apache.hive
            hive-common
            2.3.0

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive</artifactId>
        <version>0.13.1-cdh5.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.12.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.thrift</groupId>
        <artifactId>libthrift</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: You're missing some classes/JARs on the classpath when you execute the application. How are you executing this?

Comment: @ptomli  I have just added the dependecies on Pom FIle and run it on InteliJ

Comment: Looks to me like 2.8.1 doesn't actually have that class. Scanning for a definitive source, but https://fossies.org/linux/misc/hadoop-2.8.1.tar.gz/hadoop-2.8.1/share/doc/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/api/org/apache/hadoop/tracing/package-tree.html

Comment: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/tracing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see what actually causes the `loadClass` from the stack trace snippet, but it appears that the class doesn't actually exist in the version, 2.8.1, of `hadoop-common` you're using. It seems to have vanished somewhere after 2.7.2

It, or something with the same name, is in the [hbase source](https://hbase.apache.org/devapidocs/index.html?org/apache/hadoop/hbase/trace/SpanReceiverHost.html)

Have you got a mix'n'match of versions going on?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-common -->
<!-- org/apache/hadoop/tracing/SpanReceiverHost The Last version is hadoop-common 2.7.7-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```